# Can't assign/typecast ViewData to Variable, Object Reference not set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Code:

```
@{
....    
var GotAllDetails = ViewData["GetAllDetails"] as List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>;
....
}
```

and

```
@foreach (var goteem in GotAllDetails){Print my pretty list}
```

I've done plenty of debugging. I put a breakpoint right after var `GetAllDetails`, and I can confirm that `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]` is properly populated. The model I'm typecasting to has all the same value names and types as the `ViewData.` Yet, somehow, `GotAllDetails` is `null`. When the page hits my `foreach` it passes me

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Upon request, I'll share more code, but first tell me if I've made any obvious errors.

EDIT: Per Request, here's the code that specifies ViewData["GetAllDetails"]

```
ViewData["GetAllDetails"] = getAllDetails.OrderBy(q => PadString(q.TaskDescription, ".")).ToList();
```

And the LINQ Query

```
var getAllDetails =
    (from m in _db.MyStandards.AsEnumerable()
     join t in _db.Tasks on m.TaskId equals t.TaskId
     join p in _db.Products on t.ProductId equals p.ProductId
     join ce in _db.CompetencyElements on p.CompetencyElementId equals ce.CompetencyElementId
     join comp in _db.Competencies on ce.CompetencyId equals comp.CompetencyId
     join fu in _db.FunctionalUnitOfCompetences on comp.FunUnitOfCompetenceId equals fu.FunUnitOfCompetenceId
     join c in _db.Careers on fu.CareerId equals c.CareerId
     join rx in _db.RubricRefs on m.RubricStandardId equals rx.Id
     where (t.TaskId == m.TaskId && m.Email == getUserById && p.ProductId == proId)
     group new { t.TaskDescription, m.RubricStandardId, m.Comments }
     by new
     {
         c.CareerDescription,
         fu.FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc,
         comp.CompetencyDescription,
         ce.CompetencyElementdesc,
         p.ProductDescription,
         t.TaskDescription,
         m.RubricStandardId,
         m.Comments,
         m.StandardId,
         m.TaskId,
         m.ActiveInd,
         rx.RubricHexColor,
         rx.RubricSymbol
     } into g
     select new
     {
         ActiveInd = g.Key.ActiveInd,
         CareerDescription = g.Key.CareerDescription,
         Comments = g.Key.Comments,
         CompetencyDescription = g.Key.CompetencyDescription,
         CompetencyElementdesc = g.Key.CompetencyElementdesc,
         FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc = g.Key.FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc,
         ProductDescription = g.Key.ProductDescription,
         StandardId = g.Key.StandardId,
         RubricHexColor = g.Key.RubricHexColor,
         RubricStandardId = g.Key.RubricStandardId,
         RubricSymbol = g.Key.RubricSymbol,
         TaskDescription = g.Key.TaskDescription,
         TaskId = g.Key.TaskId,
     });
```

And the Model

```
public class DetailViewsModel
{
    public string ActiveInd { get; set; }
    public string  CareerDescription {get;set;}
    public string Comments {get;set;}
    public string CompetencyDescription {get;set;}
    public string CompetencyElementdesc {get;set;}
    public string FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc {get;set;}
    public string ProductDescription {get;set;}
    public int StandardId {get;set;}
    public string RubricHexColor {get;set;}
    public int RubricStandardId {get;set;}
    public string RubricSymbol {get;set;}
    public string TaskDescription {get;set;}
    public int TaskId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: "properly populated" means `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]` really returns a `List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>`? If the returned object is of a different type, the `as` operator returns `null`.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes. The ViewData is coming from a LINQ Query, and I made sure that the model I'm typecasting into has all the same values as the output from said query.

Comment: My question was not if it has the same properties. You said you debugged it, so you can debug again and determine the real type. As I said, if it's not the correct type, `GotAllDetails` will be null. If it's the case, you'll need some kind of conversion.

Comment: You said `The ViewData is coming from a LINQ Query`, please show the controller code where you set `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]`.

Comment: @ekad Got you. It's posted now.

Comment: Try to change `var GotAllDetails = ViewData["GetAllDetails"] as List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>;` to `var GotAllDetails = (List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>)ViewData["GetAllDetails"];` and see if you get a different error.

Comment: @ekad Gave me an Invalid Cast Exception error. Worth a try, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the type of `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]` is not `List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>`. What's the complete error message?

Comment: @ekad **Exception Details** : System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType27`13[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.String,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PRJ.DetailViewsModel]'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120264/discussion-between-ekad-and-uidalexd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
new  {
    ActiveInd = g.Key.ActiveInd,
    CareerDescription = g.Key.CareerDescription,
    Comments = g.Key.Comments,
    CompetencyDescription = g.Key.CompetencyDescription,
    CompetencyElementdesc = g.Key.CompetencyElementdesc,
    FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc = g.Key.FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc,
    ProductDescription = g.Key.ProductDescription,
    StandardId = g.Key.StandardId,
    RubricHexColor = g.Key.RubricHexColor,
    RubricStandardId = g.Key.RubricStandardId,
    RubricSymbol = g.Key.RubricSymbol,
    TaskDescription = g.Key.TaskDescription,
    TaskId = g.Key.TaskId,
 });
```

... doesn't yield a `DetailViewsModel`.  What it yields is a class that has the same property names and possibly property types, but it doesn't yield the SAME class.

You're going to have to instantiate an actual `DetailsViewModel` if you want what you are getting from `getAllDetails` to be castable to a `List<DetailViewsModel>`.

Fortunately, you've already done the hard part:  setting all the property values!  You should be able to substitute in this:

```
  new DetailsViewModel() {
      ActiveInd = etc.
```

Comment: It as really hard to choose between this and the other answer, but the plain-English explanation helped a lot. Thank you for breaking things down for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from this syntax

```
var GotAllDetails = ViewData["GetAllDetails"] as List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>;
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

Since you said `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]` isn't null, then `GotAllDetails` is null because the type of `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]` is not `List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>`. You need to make sure the type of `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]` is `List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>`.

Based on the linq query that produces `getAllDetails` in your question as below

```
var getAllDetails = ....
                    ....
                 select new
                 {
                     ActiveInd = g.Key.ActiveInd,
                     CareerDescription = g.Key.CareerDescription,
                     Comments = g.Key.Comments,
                     CompetencyDescription = g.Key.CompetencyDescription,
                     CompetencyElementdesc = g.Key.CompetencyElementdesc,
                     FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc = g.Key.FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc,
                     ProductDescription = g.Key.ProductDescription,
                     StandardId = g.Key.StandardId,
                     RubricHexColor = g.Key.RubricHexColor,
                     RubricStandardId = g.Key.RubricStandardId,
                     RubricSymbol = g.Key.RubricSymbol,
                     TaskDescription = g.Key.TaskDescription,
                     TaskId = g.Key.TaskId,
                 });
```

and how you set `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]`

```
ViewData["GetAllDetails"] = getAllDetails.OrderBy(q => PadString(q.TaskDescription, ".")).ToList();
```

it's clear that the type of `ViewData["GetAllDetails"]` is `List<anonymous>` instead of `List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>`.

You need to change the linq query to below

```
var getAllDetails = ....
                    ....
                 select new DetailViewsModel
                 {
                     ActiveInd = g.Key.ActiveInd,
                     CareerDescription = g.Key.CareerDescription,
                     Comments = g.Key.Comments,
                     CompetencyDescription = g.Key.CompetencyDescription,
                     CompetencyElementdesc = g.Key.CompetencyElementdesc,
                     FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc = g.Key.FunUnitOfCompetenceDesc,
                     ProductDescription = g.Key.ProductDescription,
                     StandardId = g.Key.StandardId,
                     RubricHexColor = g.Key.RubricHexColor,
                     RubricStandardId = g.Key.RubricStandardId,
                     RubricSymbol = g.Key.RubricSymbol,
                     TaskDescription = g.Key.TaskDescription,
                     TaskId = g.Key.TaskId,
                 });
```

then change this

```
var GotAllDetails = ViewData["GetAllDetails"] as List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>;
```

to this

```
var GotAllDetails = (List<PRJ.DetailViewsModel>)ViewData["GetAllDetails"];
```

so you'll know if the conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

ViewData is linked to Session. If you wish to remove your error try this.

```
var GotAlLDetails = ViewData["GetAllDetails"];

    if(GotAllDetails != null)
    {
    // do work
    }
```

Comment: It's a good failsafe, but I'm not in the market for a failsafe. Also, if I do this we get a compile time failure because `object does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator.`